# Init reference with invalid value

Tags: c++, reference

I have a class:

```
class node
{
public:

   node& parent;
}
```

I want to set the `parent` value when I know its right value:

```
node parent;
...

node n;  // here node.parent is a not valid value
n.parent = parent;
```

But I have to set it's value in the constructor too. How can I do?

Comment: Where precisely in the code do you need to set its value? And what do you want its value to be before that?

Comment: As I wrote: only when I know what is its value - A not valid value.

Comment: Then you can't use a reference. There is no such thing as a "not valid value" for a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change what variable a reference references. So if you can't initialize it in the constructor, you don't want a reference. You can use a regular pointer, but it's probably better to use some kind of smart pointer appropriate to your particular use. The correct answer depends primarily on how the lifetime of the referenced object is managed.

Comment: How is the lifetime of the parent object managed? Who destroys it? When is it destroyed? And what's supposed to happen to the "reference" when the object is destroyed? (Short version of the question: Should a node keep its parent alive? Or should a node have some kind of "invalid reference" if the parent is destroyed?)

Comment: The root node is destroyed only when I decide to destroy it, all children will be destroyed too.

Comment: Then you can just use a regular, dumb pointer. `node* parent;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use references and not pointers because you want to suggest that the class instance does not own the parent node, then you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) from C++11's `<functional>`.

I would advise against using smart pointers (except maybe `std::weak_ptr`) if the parent holds references to the children and the children hold references to the parent. Using smart pointers in this case would create a cyclic dependency, which means your objects would never get destroyed.

Comment: If he has a typical tree, using `weak_ptr` won't work. If the nodes only have weak pointers to each other, there's nothing to keep the nodes alive. You can use strong pointers, with the tree itself holding a strong pointer to the root and each node holding strong pointers to its children. When done with a node, you must disconnect its child pointers. Alternatively, the tree itself can keep a strong pointer to every node, which you disconnect to remove a node from the tree. (This is sufficiently ugly that my advice is the same as yours -- don't use smart pointers for this.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's what I meant (I thought it was obvious). Only the children should hold weak pointers to their parents and the parents should own their children.